# yii2 Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username using 2 possible authenticators

Tags: php, yii, yii2, swiftmailer

I am using swift mailer in yii2, i am using correct smtp setting still not able to send email.
I got this error - Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "example@example.com" using 2 possible authenticators

my swift mailer settings are:

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'myHostName',
            'username' => 'myUsername',
            'password' => 'myPassword',
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
        ],
    ],
```

I searched a lot on internet but found no solution, some people suggested that it would work by making 'useFileTransport' => false, but it is still not working.